# How can you make a UITextfield give suggestions and return your selection using Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, swift

The application I'm building requires a use of search bar to comb through an array and provide suggestions for what you're typing. When the suggestion from the array appears, you need to be able to select it and return it to the `UITextField`.

I have done so much research in to how to do this, but so far have had no luck, I've found some stuff in objective C but still doesn't really help me.

I know there's a bit on the internet for doing this with a `UISearchController` however, a `UISearchController` doesn't give me what I need, I need the initial search field to be in a `UITableViewCell`, not at the top of the page, if you could replace the initial search field it would work but from research i've done that is not possible.

If that is possible, please please can you tell me how because ultimately that is what i wanted.

Therefore my code so far has a `UITableview` with two sections, the first of which has the `textfield`. I want to use the second section to display the suggestions as you are typing. I'm having trouble inserting new rows and displaying suggestions based on my array, any help would be greatly appreciated, not only by me  but a number of my course mates as they are having similar issues with their final graduation projects.

**Here is my code**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

var stations: [String]
var sectionTitle: [String]

@IBOutlet weak var searchField: UITextField!

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    stations = [String]()
    stations.append("Bournemouth")
    stations.append("London")
    stations.append("Poole")

    sectionTitle = [String]()
    sectionTitle.append("Search")
    sectionTitle.append("Results")

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    tableView.rowHeight = 80;

    searchField.delegate = self
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sectionTitle.count
}

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return sectionTitle[section]
}


}

extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {


func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    println("search")


//        loop though stations array
//        let path = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 1)
//        let paths = [path]
//        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(paths, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 1))
    cell?.textLabel?.text = searchField.text


    searchField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true


}
}
```

I'm fairly certain that the are of my code I need to focus on is the following, for now I'd be happy if I could insert rows in the second section for each part of my array items, i.e loop through array and insert a new row for each item.

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sectionTitle[section]
    }


}

extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {


    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        println("search")


//        loop though stations array
//        let path = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 1)
//        let paths = [path]
//        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(paths, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 1))
        cell?.textLabel?.text = searchField.text


        searchField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true


    }
}
```